# how to get files built in vscode extension using webpack with vscode-webview-ui-toolkit

Tags: vscode-extensions

We have using @vscode/webview-ui-toolkit and it works when we are testing. But we set up the webpack version of the extension. When we package and run the extension, we are missing the toolkit and our other files. Errors like

```
Error: Unable to read file '/Users/jkh/.vscode/extensions/ext-0.0.2/node_modules/@vscode/webview-ui-toolkit/dist/toolkit.js' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file '/Users/jkh/.vscode/extensions/ext-0.0.2/node_modules/@vscode/webview-ui-toolkit/dist/toolkit.js')
```

and also the webpage src/newExtensionWizard/main.js and css src/newExtensionWizard/style.css.

Am I right that this is an issue with our webpack? Or why can we get webview-ui-toolkit to work under development but not through the vsix file?